# Google Maps Javascript API shows only a few markers out of 500+

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm currently working with the Google Maps Javascript API to display all locations for the customers. It has worked well with PHP only, but now I'm working with the $.ajax() function.

```
function init() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: {lng:  10.1293945, lat: 51.1793430}
          });
    var markers = addMarkers('', '', 'POST');
    return map;
}

function addMarkers(f, s, method) {
    console.log("Filter: " + f);
    $.ajax({
        url:      'user-load.php' + "?echo=1&method=" + method + "&filter=" + f + "&search=" + s,

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var count = data['length'];
            console.log(count + " found");
            var displayed = 0;
            for(var i = 0; i < count;  i++) {
                if(data[i]['lat'] != 0 && data[i]['lat'] != 0) {
                    displayed++;
                    var name = data[i]['first'] + " " + data[i]['last'];
                    var url = '';
                    if(data[i]['url'] != '') {  
                        url = "<p>Website: <a target=\x22_blank\x22 href=\x22" + data[i]['url'] + "\x22>" + data[i]['url'] + "</a></p>";
                    }
                    var mail = '';
                    if(data[i]['mail'] != '') {  
                        url = "<p>E-Mail: " + data[i]['mail'] + "</p>";
                    }
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position:{lng: parseInt(data[i]['lng']), lat: parseInt(data[i]['lat'])},
                        map: map,
                        title: name + ", " + data[i]['title'],
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });
                    var c = '<h1>' + name + '</h1>' + 
                                  '<h4>' + data[i]['title'] + '</h4>' +
                                  '<p>' + data[i]['Land'] + ", " + data[i]['PLZ'] + " " + data[i]['Ort'] + '</p>' +
                                  '<p>' + data[i]['Strasse'] + '</p>' +
                                  mail +
                                  url;
                    var window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content: c
                                });
                    marker.addListener('click', (function(map,marker, window){ 
                        return function() {
                            window.open(map, marker);
                        };
                    })(map, marker, window));
                    markers.push(marker);
                } else {
                    console.log("Not valid: " + data[i]);
                }
            }
            console.log(displayed + " displayed");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("ERROR!");
        }
    });
}
```

So here is my whole code. The output array of my user-load.php has no errors. It works well, the result->num_rows is equals to the markers array length, but there are only like ~50 markers out of 557. What is the problem? I'm a beginner of JS and it's a bit confusing at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED it.
Such a dumb mistake, searched it for like 5 hours.
Instead of

```
parseInt(data[i]['lng'])
```

this:

```
parseFloat(data[i]['lng'])
```

Now everything works well. Maybe I can help someone :)